# Strategies for waiting for an external process to initialize

Tags: python, python-3.x, process-management

I have 3 functions to perform:

1. Launch `tcpdump`
2. Perform network activity so that `tcpdump` can generate a pcap for it
3. Kill `tcpdump` after network activity in step 2 is complete.

#### Launch

```
def launch_tcpdump(output_filename):
    import subprocess as sp
    import time
    process = sp.Popen(['tcpdump', '-i', 'wlo1', '-w', output_filename])
    print(f"PID: {process.pid}")
    time.sleep(5)
    return process
```

if I do not sleep for 5 seconds, then before `tcpdump` gets initialized, my script completes the network activity. On the other hand, sleeping for 5 seconds seems excessive and is slowing down my overall process (I have to do this multiple times and generate pcaps for each network activity).

1. Are there ways for a child process to communicate to the parent process that it has initialized?
2. If not, can the parent process (python) check something to determine if the process has initialized?

Note: I understand that **initialized** can mean different things in the case of different processes. I am guessing that once it outputs: `tcpdump: listening on wlo1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes`, it's done initializing. So, reading stdout is also a potential option, but I am unable to find solutions that can read from stdout while detaching python from the child process.

Comment: Could you use an async process and just wait for completion?

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the output of `tcpdump` and return after however many lines.

```
import subprocess as sp
import time

def launch_tcpdump(output_filename):
    lines_to_read = 200
    process = sp.Popen(['tcpdump', '-l', '-i', 'wlo1', '-w', output_filename])
    print(f"PID: {process.pid}")
    while lines_to_read > 0:
        for _ in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
            lines_to_read -= 1
    return process
```

Notice I added the `-l` option so `tcpdump` writes to `stdout` as well as to the output file. You could also change this to check for the presence of the initialize line you mention in the `stdout`.